# Is there a compiler warning for adding 0?

Tags: compiler-warnings, gcc-warning

I just had a bug, where I used a 0-initialized variable, before it was given an actual value.

Something like:

```
int important_value = 0;

important_fun( foo + important_value );

...

important_value = 5;

important_fun( foo + important_value );
```

Probably a copy and paste bug, but that got me thinking. Is there a warning, that would've caught this error?

Surely there is no reason to add a value, that was initialized as 0 to anything.

Comment: surely no. why would a compiler ever think 0 is not a good value for int?

Comment: @bansi since it was not changed since initialisation and adding 0 makes no sense. One good argument against it would probably be loops. I figure those add initialised 0's during the first loop execution all the time.

Comment: If the compiler can figure out that the variable is always zero when this statement is executed, it will probably just remove the foo+ important_value statement

Comment: @Cheiron This would still leave the error on my part, though. Maybe it is too ambigous if it really is an error, though. Just figured it might be interesting.